# Compiling C library for Android using Clang/LLVM causes

Tags: android, c, linux, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm trying to compile a C library for Android. I have built the NDK toolchain following these instructions (that do seem to work at least for its subsequent use in Rust-based compilation) from here: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain

```sh
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
export NDK_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle

${NDK_HOME}/build/tools/make_standalone_toolchain.py --api 26 --arch arm64 --install-dir ./NDK/arm64
${NDK_HOME}/build/tools/make_standalone_toolchain.py --api 26 --arch arm --install-dir ./NDK/arm
${NDK_HOME}/build/tools/make_standalone_toolchain.py --api 26 --arch x86 --install-dir ./NDK/x86
```

As a result, I have an NDK folder with subfolders `x86`, `arm`, and `arm64`, and each one having a subfolder `bin` with such promisingly named binaries as

- `i686-linux-android-clang`
- `i686-linux-android30-clang`
- `i686-linux-android-gcc`
- `armv7a-linux-androideabi30-gcc`
- …

Next, I have a C file (`android.c`). It is taken verbatim from the `hello-jni` sample here: https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/blob/android-mk/hello-jni/jni/hello-jni.c, so hence it looks like this:

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>

jstring
Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env,
                                                  jobject thiz )
{
#if defined(__arm__)
    #if defined(__ARM_ARCH_7A__)
    #if defined(__ARM_NEON__)
      #if defined(__ARM_PCS_VFP)
        #define ABI "armeabi-v7a/NEON (hard-float)"
      #else
        #define ABI "armeabi-v7a/NEON"
      #endif
    #else
      #if defined(__ARM_PCS_VFP)
        #define ABI "armeabi-v7a (hard-float)"
      #else
        #define ABI "armeabi-v7a"
      #endif
    #endif
  #else
   #define ABI "armeabi"
  #endif
#elif defined(__i386__)
#define ABI "x86"
#elif defined(__x86_64__)
#define ABI "x86_64"
#elif defined(__mips64)  /* mips64el-* toolchain defines __mips__ too */
#define ABI "mips64"
#elif defined(__mips__)
#define ABI "mips"
#elif defined(__aarch64__)
#define ABI "arm64-v8a"
#else
#define ABI "unknown"
#endif

    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from JNI !  Compiled with ABI " ABI ".");
}
```

(I removed the comments from the source for the purpose of compactness.)  Next, I have tried various compilation commands, including all the combinations below:

- `./NDK/x86/bin/i686-linux-android30-clang -c -o ./out/libandroid_x86.so ./src/android.c`
- `./NDK/x86/bin/i686-linux-android-clang -march=i686 --target=i686-linux-android -c -o ./out/libandroid_x86.so ./src/android.c`
- `./NDK/x86/bin/i686-linux-android-gcc -c -o ./out/libandroid_x86.so ./src/android.c`

Next, I have an Android Studio project, comprised of two modules, the main app, and a library module. Inside the library module, I have a directory structure of `src/main/jniLibs`, and inside the `jniLibs` directory, I have a folder `x86` which I copy `libandroid_x86.so` into.

Now, when I run it on the simulator, which the Android Virtual Device Manager indicates is a Pixel 3a with an x86 ABI, the moment the following line gets hit:

```java
// the _x86 suffix is boxing myself into a particular architecture, but it is just for testing
System.loadLibrary("android_x86");
```

The following error is thrown:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/~~zvCaDkS-ie83kuE1PUM41A==/io.arik.android_lab-9esJAdgb21ghkft5C90DAw==/lib/x86/libandroid_x86.so" has unexpected e_type: 1

I have tried removing everything from the `android.c` file except `#include <jni.h>`, just to rule out issues pertaining to the `Java_tld_domain…` method naming convention, but even that supposedly empty shared library causes that crash.

As a further sanity check, when I build a Rust library for the same target (`cargo build --target i686-linux-android --release`) and copy the resulting library to the appropriate `jniLibs` location, the app does not crash and everything works.

The NDK tutorials and documentations appear to be rather inconsistent in terms of versioning, so my question is, what am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

**UPDATE**: I got it working by specifying $SYSROOT and, as @Antti pointed out in the comments, substituting `-c` for `-shared`:

```sh
export SYSROOT=./NDK/x86/sysroot

./NDK/x86/bin/i686-linux-android-clang -shared -Wl,-undefined -Wl,dynamic_lookup --sysroot=$SYSROOT -o ./out/libandroid_x86.so ./src/android.c
```

Comment: The main problem is `-c` switch, it means compile a translation unit to an object file. This is a switch that you **never** use with `-o something.so`. You need to make a shared object but it is not an "object file" but a partially linked loadable library. Beyond that you need the switches to *properly* compile it as a shared object for JNI, I can't remember what is needed.

Comment: I'm getting similarly little luck compiling with `-shared -Wl,-undefined -Wl,dynamic_lookup`. Thanks for your very quick comment!

Comment: I got it working with the addition of the sysroot flag: `--sysroot=$SYSROOT`, see my update. Thank you so much!